# dynamic data one by one

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm displaying dynamic data in slider can any one tell me how can i show them one by one.  I want to show data of first cell first and then it's fade in and then I want to show data of second cell after fade out on left under testimonial.  Here is link [sifrek](http://184.173.9.8/~intellis/sifrek/services.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "slider" you mean "slideshow", I'd recommend using a time-tested jQuery plugin. My favorite is [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). It has the fade in/fade out effect you're looking for.

For future reference, [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) is a slider.

Comment: i looked it and found it's a nice slider but it did not convinced my project manager :)  so I'm using jcarousellite_1.0.1c4 but thanks for help Ayman Safadi